# Returning pointer on struct member or embedded struct in Go?

Tags: go, pointers, struct, heap-memory

Taking address and returning pointer to a local variable inside a function in Go causes compiler to allocate it on heap rather than stack, so that returned pointer remains valid.

Now what happens if I take and return address of a struct member or embedded struct ?

```
type A struct {
    a,b,c int
}
type B struct {
    A
    d,e,f int
}
func (b *B) get1() *A {
    return &b.A
}
func (b *B) get2() *A {
    localB := B{}
    return &localB.A
}
```

Will compiler allocate embedded struct A on heap and keep members of B on stack ?

Will garbage collector collect localB even if localB.A reference is still in use ?

How can compiler determine when to keep embedded struct on stack or heap in case if it's accessed through reflection ?

Comment: Go is safe here. You simply **cannot** produce dangling pointers, it simply does not matter what you do (if you stay away from package unsafe). The compiler is playing safe here: If it cannot prove that allocation on the stacke is safe it will allocate on the heap. Nothing to worry about; move along.

Comment: @Volker I am not worrying about dangling pointers, but I am worrying about enclosing structure not being garbage collected soon enough.

Comment: First: type A is empty so there is nothing to collect in your example. Assuming A is not empty in real life than how could the GC collect localB if localB.A is in use? Are you assuming the GC is broken?

Comment: Assuming that A is not empty and B has other members besides A, then yes, like it was mentioned in escape analysis link from one of answers, Go escape analysis is not perfect, consequently garbage collection is not perfect too. So we can say to a certain degree that it's "broken" or better word - imperfect. Now if my structure B is big and A is small then this imperfection is important to know if I deal with millions of B. I can imagine that it should be possible for ideal GC to garbage collect parts of B even if A cannot be collected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler performs [escape analysis](http://blog.rocana.com/golang-escape-analysis) to determine whether a variable may be used outside of the scope in which it is created, in which case it must be allocated on the heap. If the compiler can make sure that this won’t happen, it allocates the variable on the stack.

However, this is the current behaviour of the compiler, but it is not mentioned in the specification, so it may change in any future version.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you even wondering about these details?

Quoting the [Go FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap) (emphasis mine):

> From a correctness standpoint, you don't need to know. Each variable
>   in Go exists as long as there are references to it. The storage
>   location **chosen by the implementation** is irrelevant to the semantics
>   of the language.

and

> In the current compilers, if a variable has its address taken, that
>   variable is a **candidate** for allocation on the heap. However, a basic
>   escape analysis recognizes some cases when such variables will not
>   live past the return from the function and can reside on the stack.

The behavior of the compiler and the garbage collector are strictly implementation-dependent, and subject to changes across different releases.
You cannot event prove your opening statement is always true: the compiler may decide to apply further optimization depending on how your function is written or invoked.